# Help needed with the xsl output as shown on Marc's page

Tags: data-view-web-part, content-query-web-part, xslt

[DVWP xsl formatting help needed](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35215/dvwp-xsl-formatting-help-needed/38032#38032)